# Sumo random Trips Xml file not generating,

Tags: xml, sumo, traffic-simulation

As soon as the command randomTrips.py -n sumotest.net.xml -o sumotest.trips.xml is given pycharm is opening, Looking for help
Thanks,
Abhiram

Answer (score 0):

Probably the file ending ".py" is not properly associated with the python executable. Try `python randomTrips.py -n sumotest.net.xml -o sumotest.trips.xml`.

Comment: Thanks, for me it worked using **py randomTrips.py**